# Windows 10 Mobile AssignedAccessXml: Disable "related settings" for blocked settings pages

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-iot-core, lockdown

I am experimenting with locking down a device running Windows 10 Mobile enterprise, using Microsoft EnterpriseAssignedAccess CSP, most specifically AssignedAccess.xml (aka lockdown.xml). I am facing an issue with being able to indirectly access the screens I am trying to block.

The  configuration only seems to "hide" the setting screen but does not effectively block access to the settings through any other entry points.

For instance, if I block access to the "Storage" screen (SettingsPageStorageSenseStorageOverview), it stops showing in the setting menu as expected.

However, the Networking & Wireless / Data usage screen contains a "Related Settings" link that opens the Storage screen. This defeats the purpose of attempting to block access to the Storage screen in the first place.

Is there a way to disable "Related Settings"?